# creating service accounts in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, service, account

How can I create a **service account** such as **SQL service** in active directory on Win server 2008 R2?
I dont know in which part of *administrative tools* that it can be found.

Comment: A service account is just like any other account - there's no distinction. Just create a new account like you would for a normal user.

Answer (score 2):

First Confirm that the Managed Users Service Account Container exists using the MMC Active Directory Groups and Users tool:

Second Use Windows PowerShell to create the accounts by running the two commands in lines steps 5 & 6  below:

1. Click Start
2. Click All Progams
3. click Windows PowerShell 2.0, and
4. then click the Windows PowerShell icon.
5. Run the following command: Import-Module ActiveDirectory
6. Run the following command: New-ADServiceAccount [-SAMAccountName ] [-Path ].

If you omit the parameters, the power shell will provide prompts that allow you to supply the name.

That't all there is to it.